# Finding top-n "friends" with common interest

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created a node for each of 25 Seminars and a node for each of 70 Clients.

Seminars occur multiple times a month in no particular sequence, and each Seminar hosts only 5 Clients at a time and could be any 5 of the 70.  I am currently capturing each occurrence of a Seminar as well as who attended:

```
MATCH (c1:Client {id: cid}), ..., (c5:Client {id: cid}), (s:Seminar {id: sid})
WITH c1, c2, c3, c4, c5
CREATE UNIQUE (c1)-[:ATTENDED {event_id: eid}]->(s)
...
CREATE UNIQUE (c5)-[:ATTENDED {event_id: eid}]->(s)
WITH c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, s
MERGE (c1)-[x:WITH]-(c2)
ON MATCH SET x.count = x.count + 1
ON CREATE SET x.count = 1
...repeat for c1 & c3, c1 & c4, c1 & c5
WITH c2, c3, c4, c5
...repeat c2 & c3, c2 & c4, c2 & c5
WITH c3, c4, c5
...repeat for c3 & c4, c3 & c5...
WITH c4, c5
MERGE (c4)-[x:WITH]-(c5)
ON MATCH SET x.count = x.count + 1
ON CREATE SET x.count = 1;
```

For a new Event:

```
(x:Seminar {event_id: xid})
```

I would like to "target" the top-5 clients that have attended various seminars such that

```
(:Client)-[r:WITH]-(:Client) WHERE r.count >= 1
```

The goal is to gather Clients who are "most familiar" with each other.  How do I code this query? Do I have enough information (relationships and properties)?  Is there a better way to add the event data?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest an alternative to building up your :WITH relationships.

```
MATCH (c:Client)-[:ATTENDED]->(:Seminar)<-[:ATTENDED]-(co:Client)
WITH c, co, COUNT(co) as timesWith
MERGE (c)-[r:WITH]-(co)
SET r.count = timesWith
```

This gets you a row for each client, a client they attended seminars with, and the number of times they attended a seminar with them, and saves (or updates) that count on your :WITH relationships.

You can also make your query for creating seminars and the relationships between clients and seminars much easier, if you can supply a collection of ids as the parameter to your query, as you can do this all at once instead of individually:

```
MATCH (c:Client), (s:Seminar {id: sid})
WHERE c.id IN {attendeeIDs}
MERGE (c)-[:ATTENDED]->(s)
// and then you can run the query above to update WITH relationships if necessary
```

As for the rest of what you want, that's a rather tricky query, and I'm not sure if you've made it clear what your approach should be.

Are you looking for a set of 5 :Clients such as the sum of the counts of the :WITH relationships between them is the greatest of any other set of 5? Because that kind of query will require you to test every combination of 5 clients and perform that calculation, and we'll also have to take extra care to ensure we do this with combinations, rather than permutations.

Even then, it will be very costly query, as the number of combinations of sets of 5 out of 70 possibilities is C(70,5) = 12,103,014. That is a lot of rows built up and operations to be run on every single one of those rows.

```
// first match on a combination of 5; id inequalities prevent permutations
MATCH (c1:Client), (c2:Client), (c3:Client), (c4:Client), (c5:Client)
WHERE id(c1) < id(c2) < id(c3) < id(c4) < id(c5)
WITH c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, [id(c1),id(c2),id(c3),id(c4),id(c5)] as ids
// find all possible :WITH relationships between each set of 5
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r:WITH]-(b)
WHERE id(a) in ids AND id(b) in ids
WITH c1,c2,c3,c4,c5, SUM(r.count) as togetherness
ORDER BY togetherness DESC
RETURN c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
LIMIT 1
```

There are ways to make this more efficient. Rather than looking at all :Clients, you might first try to get the top n or so :Clients based on seminars attended, and then try run a similar query.

This is how it might look if you selected the top 15 attendees as far as seminar attendance first, then tried to find the group of 5 that has been together the most out of those 15:

```
MATCH (c:Client)
WITH c, SIZE((c)-[:ATTENDED]->(:Seminar)) as attendance
ORDER BY attendance DESC
WITH c
LIMIT 15
WITH COLLECT(id(c)) as ids
// first match on a combination of 5; id inequalities prevent permutations
MATCH (c1:Client), (c2:Client), (c3:Client), (c4:Client), (c5:Client)
WHERE id(c1) in ids, id(c2) in ids, id(c3) in ids, id(c4) in ids, id(c5) in ids
 AND id(c1) < id(c2) < id(c3) < id(c4) < id(c5)
WITH c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, [id(c1),id(c2),id(c3),id(c4),id(c5)] as ids
// find all possible :WITH relationships between each set of 5
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r:WITH]-(b)
WHERE id(a) in ids AND id(b) in ids
WITH c1,c2,c3,c4,c5, SUM(r.count) as togetherness
ORDER BY togetherness DESC
RETURN c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
LIMIT 1
```